Query array of sub nested field in elasticsearch
I have a document that looks like this
{
  "_index": "my_index",
  "_id": "1277-fr-123456",
  "_version": 3,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "companyName": "My company",
    "portfolios": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "PF_CONF_001",
        "item": {
          "reference": "Référence client",
          "id": 32
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "PF_CONF_002",
        "item": {
          "reference": "Référence ABC",
          "id": 31
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

The mapping for the index is as follow
{
    "mappings":
    {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties":
        {
            "companyName":
            {
                "type": "keyword",
                "fields":
                {
                    "autocomplete":
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "lower_ascii_analyzer"
                    },
                    "sortable":
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "lower_ascii_analyzer",
                        "fielddata": true
                    }
                }
            },
            "portfolios":
            {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties":
                {
                    "id":
                    {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "item":
                    {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties":
                        {
                            "reference":
                            {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "lower_ascii_analyzer"
                            },
                            "id":
                            {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "name":
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "lower_ascii_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

One document can have mutiple portfolios, and each portfolio contains one item, that contains a reference.
How do I query documents where portfolios.item.reference = abc. I want my query to be case insensitive.
I tried this
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "portfolios.item",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "*abc*",
                    "default_field": "item.reference",
                    "analyze_wildcard": true,
                    "allow_leading_wildcarrd": true,
                    "analyzer": "lower_ascii_analyzer"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

and
{
    "query":
    {
        "bool":
        {
            "must":
            [
                {
                    "nested":
                    {
                        "path": "portfolios.item",
                        "query":
                        {
                            "bool":
                            {
                                "must":
                                {
                                    "match":
                                    {
                                        "item.reference": "*abc*"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

And other varations, but I couldn't get it to work.

Ok I found how to do it. I have to specify the full path of each nested object
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "portfolios",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "portfolios.item",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "query_string": {
                          "query": "*abc*",
                          "default_field": "portfolios.item.reference",
                          "analyze_wildcard": true,
                          "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
                          "analyzer": "lower_ascii_analyzer"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


I think you should go one level higher as well.
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "portfolios",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "item",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "item.reference": {
                            "query": "abc",
                            "operator": "and",                        
                            "analyze": "lower_ascii"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I did not try it but please give it a shot.
As far as I know using leading wildcards like *
"query": "*abc*"

reduces the performance of elasticsearch.

Thanks for your answer. I tried but it doesn't work because "reason": "[match] query does not support [analyze]",. So I tried with a query_string and I get this error "reason": "failed to create query: [nested] failed to find nested object under path [item]",

Can you please try replacing this: "analyze": "lower_ascii" with  "analyzer": "lower_ascii_analyzer"

I still got "reason": "failed to create query: [nested] failed to find nested object under path [item]",
